# How do I access RegExp matching group contents?

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

How can I access the matching group string in Google apps script?  The following code returns all of the string, not just the matching group text.

`(/([\d\.]+)]]/).exec("abcdefg 123.45]]")[0]`

returns `123.45]]`

I want to return `123.45`, not `123.45]]`, which is what the above code returns.

Comment: Then use unambiguous regex patterns. `/([\d.]+)\]\]/` and access the group 1 value. Note the literal notation is preferable as you do nothave to double escape special regex characters.

Comment: Try `(/([\d\.]+)]]/).exec("abcdefg 123.45]]")[1]` as that is where the number is captured to. Or just use `str.match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\]{2})/g)` that will return all found floats found before 2 `]`s or `null` if not found.

Comment: Yes, you answered twice :) Do you understand the difference between `match` and `exec`? Shall I add an answer? Note your regex will also match `.12....112..]]`, no idea if you mean to match such substrings.

Answer (score 2):

The exec function's first array element in the returned value is the entire match.  You need to access the second element:

`(/([\d\.]+)]]/).exec("abcdefg 123.45]]")[1]`

See [JavaScript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

> result    [0] The full string of characters matched
>
> [1], ...[n ]    The parenthesized substring matches, if any. The number
> of possible parenthesized substrings is unlimited.